# mongoid sort by existence of date field

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I have a mongoid model which has a created_at and a resolved_at, DateTime.

I'd like to have the unresolved objects (resolved_at=nil) tickets first, and then sorted by the created_at date descending.

How can I do that in mongoid? Something like:

```
Ticket.order_by([ :resolved_at.exists.asc, :created_at.desc ])
```

Sorts them exclusively based on resolved_at. I'm probably looking for something like :resolved_at.exists.asc, but that doesn't seem to be a valid option.